# Excel Conditional Formatting IF formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to find a formula for the following example scenario:

In column A will be a 'Yes' or 'No' value. 
In column B will be a numerical value.

If the cell in column A is 'Yes' I would like the cell in column C to copy the value from the cell in column B.

Is this possible, if so what is the formula for this? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot 'copy the value from the cell in column B' with **Conditional Formatting**.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realise this could not be done. I have used the formula directly into the cell instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following formula will do that

```
=IF(A1="Yes",B1,"")
```

*Writing answer instead of commenting because of less reputation score*

Comment: I am applying this formula to all rows in the spreadsheet, and so the values in column B will be different on each row, therefore I don't think the last part of that formula, " " , will work? Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Emily The "" part in the formula is for the case when the value in column A is not "Yes". Can you provide the sample of input data and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: I was trying to use this formula in Conditional Formatting which as @Jeeped said, will not work. When I enter the formula you stated into the cell and drag it down the column to apply to all cells, then this works as I required. Thank you for your help.